# return nested template member in non template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, member

I want to make a event class having a member of any types of data, and make it a non-template class.
but it can set content giving a template type of content.
I have handler functions which are using content of event class.

NewEvent.h file

```
class NewEvent {
public:
  NewEvent(const int64_t& value = 0) : value_(value) {}

  int64_t value() const { return value_; }
  void set_value(const int64_t& value) { value_ = value; }

  class ElementBase {
  public:
    virtual ~ElementBase() {}
    template <typename ContentT> ContentT& content() const;
    template <typename ContentT> void set_content(const ContentT&);
  };

  template <typename ContentT, typename Allocator = std::allocator<ContentT>>
  class Element : public ElementBase {
  public:
    Element(const Allocator& alloc = Allocator()) : alloc_(alloc) {}

    typedef std::allocator_traits<Allocator> AllocatorTraits;

    ContentT& content() const {
      return content_;
    }
    void set_content(const ContentT& content) {
      AllocatorTraits::construct(alloc_, &content_, content);
    }

  protected:
    ContentT content_;
    Allocator alloc_;
  };

  template <typename ContentT>
  void set_content(ContentT& content) {
    ElementBase* element = new Element<ContentT>();
    element->set_content(content);
    content_.reset(element);
  }

  template <typename ContentT>
  ContentT& content() const {
    return content_->content<ContentT>();
  }

private:
  int64_t value_;

  std::unique_ptr<ElementBase> content_;
};

template <typename ContentT>
ContentT& NewEvent::ElementBase::content() const {
  return dynamic_cast<NewEvent::Element<ContentT>&>(*this).content();
}

template <typename ContentT>
void NewEvent::ElementBase::set_content(const ContentT& content) {
  dynamic_cast<NewEvent::Element<ContentT>&>(*this).set_content(content);
}
```

Main.cpp

```
struct Data {
    int returns;
};
void print(Data data) {
}
int main() {
    struct Data data;
    // ...
    NewEvent new_event;
    new_event.set_content<Data>(data);

    print(new_event.content());
    return 0;
}
```

in my code, set_content function works well.
but I don't know how to receive content() and call according to type of content.
content() function in NewEvent class has a compile error.

error C2783: 'ContentT &NewEvent::ElementBase::content(void) const' : could not deduce template argument for 'ContentT'

How to solve this deducing type problem, or is there other methods to implement like this?

Answer (score 0):

In your function:

```
template <typename ContentT>
ContentT& content() const { .. }
```

`ContentT` here cannot be *deduced* - you're not providing anything when you call it that the compiler can use to determine which version of `content()` to call (hence the error). How can it know whether you want `content<Date>()` or `content<int>()` or ...? You have to explicitly provide the type at the call site in the same way you did when you called `set_content()`:

```
print(new_event.content<Date>()); // now compiler knows which content() to call.
```

(Note that what you're implementing is effectively the same as [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/any.html), in case you want to use that type instead.)